# Run SSRS subscription with different parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to programmatically execute an existing subscription with different report parameters?

So far I execute subscriptions via SQL as follows:

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent 'TimedSubscription', '<Subscriptions.SubscriptionID>'
```

But this seems to only allow me to execute the subscription as-is.

Edit:
I wanted to do this for our existing subscriptions (50+ total).
Manually re-creating each subscription is not feasible.

Comment: One way to do this would be to create the report and a subscription and set all the subscription's report parameters that you want to change per run to  "Use Default" for value (on the subscription side). You can then send in information and calculate your parameter values when you report is being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

[The first commenter in this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2009/11/24/calling-ssrs-report-using-either-t-sql-or-ssis.aspx) updates the `Parameters` value in the `Subscriptions` table via a Stored Procedure before running the `AddEvent` command:

```
update Subscriptions 
set Parameters=    
'<ParameterValues><ParameterValue><Name>Value</Name><Value>' + @value + '</Value></ParameterValue></ParameterValues>'
where SubscriptionID='XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked through this problem was to set up a data driven subscription on the report that populated the parameters based on the values held within a specifically designed SQL table.  I then set up a stored procedure that populated that table with the values that were required and then fired the subscription using `AddEvent`.

You may run into issues with this approach if you need to run fire the subscriptions more frequently than it takes to produce the report and thus cleaning out the lookup table.  If the report isn't that frequent though, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could take 2 of the following approaches:

**Approach 1**

Step 1: Navigate to the report you would like run with different parameters.
Step 2: Select to manage the report 
Step 3: Select to Create Linked Report 
Step 4: Choose the location where the report can live.
Step 5: For the new linked report, click to manage the report 
Step 6: Change the default parameters you'd like passed 
Step 7: Create subscription for new linked report.

**Approach 2**

Step 1:  Navigate to the report you would like run with different parameters.
Step 2: Select to manage the report.
Step 3: Create a subscription for the report 
Step 3a: While creating subscription, specify what values you want passed.

Hope this helps!